# How to autosave a checkbox state using Jquery, SQL and DB for each user?

Tags: php, checkbox

I had a look around first and there's answers for Andriod users but not for a general DB.

I don't know where to start (or if it's possible), so I'm looking for a user to log into my site and there's rows with checkboxes to the side.  The user would be able to tick each task completed.

How to record each checkbox click and get it saved to the DB without formally creating a full form and submit function?

Comment: I think you are probably looking to use the AJAX technique

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should add a click event listener to the checkbox. Whenever the task is checked, you should call the URL (or endpoint) using the JS Fetch API which will process the request and save the data.

Comment: Take a look into this pen: https://codepen.io/castroalves/pen/OJPwVmW